# Looking for an Image Conversion Library

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, image-conversion

I am looking for a conversion library that can convert my dds files to tga. I found [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/). But both come with problems, because my specifications are as follows:

- The library needs to be a 64-bit dll
- The library needs to be managed (writing in C#)

DevIL has a wrapper called [DevIL.NET](http://www.mastropaolo.com/devildotnet/), but this is 32-bits. I already tried to build the source in 64-bit, but I was missing a file and the author doesn't seem to respond at the moment.

ImageMagick doesn't seem to support [dds formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).

Does anybody know a good library that complies to my requirements?

Comment: How large are the Images? (in Terms of GB)
Will you really leverage the 64-bits Version?

Comment: I require a 64-bits version, because the plugin I am creating will be for 3D studio Max 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this but it's a bit painfull.

[Humus](http://humus.name/) provides C++ source code for both tga and dds reading and saving ( Download the latest framework ). You need to convert it to C# but this should be possible without any problems ( i did it once too ).

You'll find the code in the `Imaging\Image.h` and `Imaging\Image.cpp`.
[Direct link to the Code( ZIP ).](http://humus.name/3D/Framework3.zip)

Comment: Can you be more specific with a link? There is a lot of stuff on the site.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Added the direct link to the ZIP archive which contains the code.